# Counting labels in a program using C

Tags: c, label

I have tried to count the number of labels present in a C program, using C itself. It works good. I extended it like, I have an array `ca[]`, which contains line numbers as elements. When the corresponding lines are read, the line should not be searched for labels. The concept behind this is, I will receive an array from another program, that contains line numbers of comment lines. So, I will get the array as input, and skip processing those lines alone.

What I have tried is,

```
int nl=0,flag=0,i=1,j=0;
int ca[100]={3,5};
char c;

fp=fopen("chumma.c","r");

while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
{
if(c=='\n')
    i=i+1;
if((ca[j])!=i)
{

    if(c==':')
        flag=1;

    else if((flag==1) && (c=='\n'))
    {      
      flag=0;nl++;
    }

}
else
   j++;
}
```

`nl` is the number of labels. This doesn't check the lines itself. Kindly guide me where I have went wrong.

Comment: For one, C comments are not entire lines.  Second, `case n:` and `default:` probably shouldn't count as labels.  Third, what about `:` inside quoted strings?

Comment: @BenVoigt You are right, but I want it to include case statements also for LLOC count( I will declude this count from LLOC). But, am using it in a small scale only. So, I just haven't considered the ':' inside quoted strings, for now.

Comment: You should implement C code for:

`grep "^[ \t]*[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*:" | grep -v "^[ \t]*default:"` over preprocessed file.

Comment: Also I recommend to always call fclose for each fopen, also for any other disposable resource (dynamical memory and so on). Yes, OS will cleanup some of this at the process exit, but such practice/idiom is very important, especially for C.

Comment: err... I forgot about `"some text...\nlabel: some more text" case`....

Comment: @Yury: OS will cleanup *all* of it. And it's a good practice, but only beneficial for long-lived processes.

Comment: What about ternary operator `a=b?label_look_alike:expression;`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes, OS will close file handles and free heap, but no all other possible resources. There could be DB connections, transactions, non-temporary files to be deleted, non-serialized data in some "classes" and so on. I agree, that it's sometimes non-important for mini-programs, and my advice is not a general rule, only an advice.

Comment: ... and character constants... `':'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,,

```
int nl=0,flag=0,i=1,j=0;
int ca[100]={3,5};
char c;

fp=fopen("Kiss.c","r");

while ((c=getc(fp))!=EOF) {

if (c == '\n') {
    if (ca[j] == i) j ++;

    if (flag == 1) {      
        flag = 0; nl ++;
    }

    i = i ++;
    continue;
}

if (ca[j] == i)
    continue;

if (c==':')
    flag=1;
```

Comment: Thanks. But, what if I have to check more than one ':' in a single line?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like homework/a learning exercise, so I'm going to explain the process of planning/designing a program like this. Then I'll give you a sample of one way to implement it.

One way to write these kinds of programs is by building a pair of state machines:

1. Initial state/whitespace state
2. From state 1: Have seen `/*` sequence; stay in this state until `*/`; return to 1
3. From state 1: Have seen `"` character; stay in this state until `\` or `"`; return to 1
4. From state 1: Have seen `//` sequence; stay in this state until newline; return to 1
5. From state 1: Have seen a letter; stay in this state capturing until nonletter and nondigit
6. From state 1: Have seen anything else, stay in this state until newline.
7. From state 3: Have seen `\` extract next character, then go back to state 3

Once leaving state 5:

- If the word is `switch` we'll go into our other state machine (below).
- If we didn't see `:` then return to state 1
- Otherwise our word is a label; do whatever you want with it and return to state 1.

When we see `switch`, though, we need another state table because of the expression that immediately follows:

1. Initial state/whitespace
2. From state 1: `(` at start after `switch`
3. From state 1: All other characters generate an ***error***.
4. From state 2: `/*` and `"` get treated as in state machine 1 (above)
5. From state 2: `)` seen
6. From state 5: `{` - increment nesting level and go immediately to state 7.
7. Whitespace/state
8. From state 7: `}` - decrement nesting level on entrance to this state; if at nesting level zero, then return to state 1 in first state machine, otherwise remain in state 7.
9. From state 7: Have seen a letter; stay in this state capturing until nonletter or `:`
10. From state 7: Have seen anything else, stay in this state until `;` or `}` moving to states 7 and 8 respectively.

Once leaving state 9:

- If we didn't see `:` then go to state 10
- Otherwise if the word as `default` then go to state 10
- Otherwise this is a label; do whatever you want with it and go to state 10

The next step is to write a function for each state. It may be helpful to number the states and give the functions numbers. The way they operate on the "character" or "character sequence" is generally with a couple low level things I write early:

```
int c;
int next() { c=getchar(); return c; }
typedef int (*state)();
```

For example, states 2 and 3 above might be written as:

```
state state2() { if(c == '*' && next() == '/') return state1; return state2; }
state state3() { if(c == '"') return state1; if (c == '\\') return state7; }
```

It should be pretty easy to work out the rest of the states. State 5 will have a buffer that you're filling up to "read" the word:

```
char word[600];
int ptr;
state state5() { 
  ptr = 0;
  while(isdigit(c) || isalpha(c)) {
    word[ptr] = c;
    ptr++;
    if(ptr==600)abort();
    next();
  }
  /* now leaving state 5 */
}
```

Once you're done with this, you can write the driver:

```
void statemachine1() {
  state x = state1;
  while(c != -1) x = x();
}
```

If you've made a mistake, it will be helpful to have some debugging tools. One good one is to label each state in an array:

```
state statelist1[] = { state1, state2, state3, state4, state5, state6, state7 };
int statenumber(state x) {
  int i, n = sizeof(statelist1) / sizeof(state);
  while(n-->0) if(x == statelist1[n]) return n;
  abort();
}
```

This would be helpful when debugging; I might insert:

```
printf("state = %d, char = %02x (%c)\n", statenumber(x), c,c);
```

into the driver loop, and something like this:

```
printf("char = %02x (%c)\n", c,c);
```

in various parts as I trace the machine. This would build up a map in my mind more firmly of the state machine, and as I follow it along my test programs, it will make it easier to validate all of the states.

If things start getting difficult, I'll modify `next()` to keep track of the current line:

```
int line = 1;
int next() { c=getchar(); if(c == '\n') line++; return c; }
```

that way I can use that in my `printf()` statements as well.

Once I'm satisfied things are working, I'll remove the debugging code.

Good luck!